# How to detect a new line of any file using C program

Tags: c, arrays, file, newline, scanf

I am reading a file of integers. I want to save integers from each line to a new array. For this I want to detect a new line of a file. If anybody knows this please help.

The file to be read is as follows

```
1 2 4 5 6
7 3 2 5 
8 3 
9 7 6 2
```

Comment: Well, what do you have so far? Do you know how to open a file and read from it? Do you know how to read a line at a time?

Comment: [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) reads **lines** from the input stream. Use it and [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    FILE *fp = fopen ( "d:\\abc.txt", "r");
    char line[1024];
    char ch = getc ( fp );
    int index = 0;
    while ( ch != EOF ) {
        if ( ch != '\n'){
            line[index++] = ch;
        }else {
            line[index] = '\0';
            index = 0;

            printf ( "%s\n", line );
        }
        ch = getc ( fp );
    }


    fclose ( fp );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is some segmentation fault in this program... I am trying to find out the reason....

Comment: I do not get any segmentation fault, Please note that line is limited to 1024. This is example code , you can extend it further.

Answer (score 9):

Why not use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) to get one line at a time from the file?  You can then use [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) instead of `fscanf()` to extract the integers.

Comment: This is a great advice, since it reduces the number of system call to only one each line, instead of one each character. Great for performance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` to read a single line of input at a time. Then use `strtol()` to parse off an integer, using its "end pointer" feature to figure out where to try again, and loop until you've parsed all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getc()` for this action is fine but do not forget that `getc()` returns type is int. Retype to char "works" but you can have a problem with non strict-ASCII input file because `EOF = -1 = 0xFF` after retype to char (on most C compilers), i.e. `0xFF` characters are detected as `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *p;
    int n;
    int s=0;
    int a[10];
    p=fopen("C:\\numb.txt","r");
    if(p!=NULL)
        printf("file opened");

    while((n=getc(p))!=EOF)
    {   if(n!=NULL && n!='\n')
      {
        printf("\n%d",n);
        a[s]=n;
        ++s;
      }
    }
fclose(p);
getchar();
}
```

I'm not sure of the int to char and vice versa conversion but program works for non zero numbers. I tried on visual basic.

Answer (score -1):

If you use reading char by char then recognizing whitespace with '32' and 'enter' by '13' and/or '10'

Comment: Never hardcode ASCII values. Use character constants, such as ' ' for space, '\n' for line feed, '\r' for carriage return. Also use isspace() when that is what you mean.